# Show related entries grouped by category with category title and description

Tags: categories, relations, relatedto

Anyone able to direct me on this?
I have a page that allows you to pick related entries (cables) within the page I want to output the related entries (cables) but group them by their category. I have the following code by this is adding each cable into each category and not just the cable within the right category.

```
<div class="container // island-bottom">
    {% set categories = craft.categories.group('cables') %}

    {# {% set cables = craft.entries.section('cables').order('title').limit(null) %} #}

    {% set cables = entry.cables %}

    {% for entry in cables %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for category in categories.relatedTo(cables) %}
        <div class="cableGroup">
            <h2 class="panel__title">{{ category }}</h2>
            <div class="cableGroup__description content // margin-bottomX2">
                {{ category.description }}
            </div>

            <ul>
                {% for entry in cables %}
                    <li class="cable">
                        <a href="#{{ entry.title|camel|upper }}" data-title="{{ entry.title }} &#xa;">
                            <img src="/assets/img/tmp/cable.jpg" alt="{{ entry.title }}">
                            <h3 class="cable__tag">{{ entry.title }}</h3>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            {% for entry in cables.relatedTo(category) %}
                <div id="{{ entry.title|camel|upper }}" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal__close">
                        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal__closeBtn">
                            <span class="label close"><span class="icon-close heavy"></span>Close</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal__content // cable__modal">
                        <div class="cable__img">
                            <img src="/assets/img/tmp/cable.jpg" alt="{{ entry.title }}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="cable__content">
                            <h3 class="cable__title">
                                {{ entry.title }}
                            </h3>
                            <p>{{ entry.cableDescription }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of [Tim Kelty's groupBy plugin](https://github.com/timkelty/craft-groupby/blob/master/README.md) and some initial direction from @stephenlewis (thanks). The following code seems to have resolved my issue. I am little surprised this couldn't be achieved natively though. Unless there is a native solution, but I tried various approaches.

```
<div class="container // island-bottom">

{% set cables       = entry.cables.find() %}
{% set cableCats    = craft.categories.group('cables') %}

{% set groupedEntries = cables|groupBy('cableCategory.title') %}
{% for cableGroups in groupedEntries %}
<div class="cableGroup">
    {% for category in cableCats.relatedTo(cableGroups) %}
    <h2 class="panel__title">{{ category.title }}</h2>
    <div class="cableGroup__description content // margin-bottomX2">
        {{ category.description }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for cable in cableGroups %}
        {% if loop.first %}<ul>{% endif -%}
            <li class="cable">
                <a href="#{{ cable.title|camel|upper }}" data-title="{{ cable.title }} &#xa;">
                    <img src="/assets/img/tmp/cable.jpg" alt="{{ cable.title }}">
                    <h3 class="cable__tag">{{ cable.title }}</h3>
                </a>
            </li>
        {% if loop.last %}</ul>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for cable in cableGroups %}
        <div id="{{ cable.title|camel|upper }}" class="modal">
            <div class="modal__close">
                <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal__closeBtn">
                    <span class="label close"><span class="icon-close heavy"></span>Close</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="modal__content // cable__modal">
                <div class="cable__img">
                    <img src="/assets/img/tmp/cable.jpg" alt="{{ cable.title }}">
                </div>

                <div class="cable__content">
                    <h3 class="cable__title">
                        {{ cable.title }}
                    </h3>
                    <p>{{ cable.cableDescription }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your example is a trifle confusing, but in answer to your general question about grouping entries by a category field, [Tim Kelty's groupBy plugin](https://github.com/timkelty/craft-groupby/blob/master/README.md) may help.

For example:

```
{% set groupedEntries = allEntries|groupBy('myCategoryField.title', 'Oddments') %}
{% for categoryTitle, categoryEntries in groupedEntries %}
    <h2>{{ categoryTitle }}</h2>

    {% for categoryEntry in categoryEntries %}
        {{ categoryEntry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Is this not possible without a plugin?

Comment: I have this working, in that they are grouped and only those entries showing but I can't seem to be able to also show the description for each category as well as the title? Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, right. If you need additional information about the category (such as the description), the above won't work. [This Craft Cookbook recipe](https://craftcookbook.net/recipes/category-group-based-tabs-grouping-entries-by-categories) should point you in the right direction.